# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x138cb4d0> was mutated while being enumerated

Tags: objective-c, ios

i am trying to remove duplicate objects from array.

```
 NSMutableArray* filterResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    BOOL copy;

    // remove duplicate
    if (![arrSelectedVehicle count] == 0)
    {
        for (Vehicles *a1 in arrSelectedVehicle) {
            copy = YES;
            for (Vehicles *a2 in filterResults) {
                if ([a1.Vehicle_id isEqualToString:a2.Vehicle_id]) {
                    copy = NO;
                    [arrSelectedVehicle removeObjectIdenticalTo:a2];
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (copy) {
                [filterResults addObject:a1];
            }
        }
    }
```

i am adding two object which is already their in the array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you cannot modify an array when you are enumerating it. you can do the following:

```
 NSMutableArray* filterResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
BOOL copy;

// remove duplicate
if (![arrSelectedVehicle count] == 0)
{
NSArray* arraycopy = [arrSelectedVehicle copy];
    for (Vehicles *a1 in arraycopy) {
        copy = YES;
        for (Vehicles *a2 in filterResults) {
            if ([a1.Vehicle_id isEqualToString:a2.Vehicle_id]) {
                copy = NO;
                [arrSelectedVehicle removeObjectIdenticalTo:a2];
                break;
            }
        }
        if (copy) {
            [filterResults addObject:a1];
        }
    }
[arraycopy release];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify an array while using it with fast enumeration. That's what the error is telling you. You need to change the loops

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < arrSelectedVehicle.count; i++) {
    Vehicles *a1 = arrSelectedVehicle[i];
    copy = YES;
    for (NSUInteger j = 0; j < filterResults.count; j++) {
        Vehicles *a2 = filterResults[j];

        if ([a1.Vehicle_id isEqualToString:a2.Vehicle_id]) {
            copy = NO;
            [arrSelectedVehicle removeObjectIdenticalTo:a2];
            break;
        }
    }
    if (copy) {
        [filterResults addObject:a1];
    }
}
```

Comment: if their is a two identical object than only one is remove.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code.  Anyway, the easiest way to remove duplicates, if you don't care about the order of the elements, is using an `NSSet`, because an `NSSet` doesn't allow duplicates:

```
NSArray *uniqueObjects = [[NSSet setWithArray:arrSelectedVehicle] allObjects];
```

Comment: If you want a mutable array, send a `mutableCopy` message at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it pretty much: you can't modify the contents of a mutable collection while you're using fast enumeration on it (because that's erroneous). You have to make a mutable copy of it, and remove the duplicates from that copy.

Answer (score 0):

you can not use a for loop and then add or remove objects from the array that you are iterating through (arrSelectedVehicle). Instead try building up a new array with the objects that are OK. At the end of the loop you could assign that array back to arrSelectedVehicle.

Comment: You can use a `for` loop. You just can't use the fast enumeration type of `for` loop.