# 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <CALayerArray: 0x17485f7a0> was mutated while being enumerated

Tags: ios, for-loop, foreach, nsarray

> i found crash code in my project but i do not what is wrong in this code , Please me

```
for(NSMutableDictionary *dict  in sortedArray)
{
NSNumber *dist = dict[kDistance];
for(DRMapView * mapObj  in mapViewDataArrayNew)
{
if([mapObj.mDistance isEqualToNumber:dist])
{
[self.barsDataArray addObject:mapObj];
}
}
}
```

> some one say use index for loop 
>   how replace for each with index for loop
>
> Advance Thanks

Comment: What is the data type of barsDataArray? Please format & explain your question as much as possible for better response. Try to explain all your variables & data type.

Comment: in which line your code stopped ?

Comment: self.barsDataArray is NSMuatble object ?

Comment: you cannot modify an array when you are enumerating it. you can do the following: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14152891/3901620

Comment: self.barsDataArray  is mutable array, sortedArray is mutable array  ,mapviewdataarraynew is mutable array

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate a copy and change original

```
 NSDictionary dictCopy = [THE_ORIGINAL_DICT copy];
 for(NSMutableDictionary *dict  in dictCopy)
    {
        NSNumber *dist = THE_ORIGINAL_DICT[kDistance];
        for(DRMapView * mapObj  in mapViewDataArrayNew)
        {
            if([mapObj.mDistance isEqualToNumber:dist])
        {
        [self.barsDataArray addObject:mapObj];
        }
    }
    }
```